# Standard Deviation ( Sort of ) Problem

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I have a bunch of particles spread over a 2D area.  I plan to fit a a distribution to describe the spread.

To start off :

1. I have about 100 particles arranged in a circular pattern in a "unit" consisting of 10 pieces ( like a pizza basically ).  There are then 10 of these "units" arranged in a cylindrical shape all contained in a cylindrical shell.
2. A charge ignites at the back of the cylinder, sending the projectiles forward.

My argument is that the front pieces will be pushed by the rear ones, and result in a higher spread for the first 2-3 rows, whereas the last few rows will see a tighter spread as there are no particles "pushing" them out of the way.

If I were to draw a scatter plot of the spread, it would be slightly concentrated in the middle and increase from there to a point and then drop off.

I estimate it to look something like this if I were to view a line from the centre to the edge:

[image: Prob Plot]

This distribution will then be rotated around the centre to from a kind of "doughnut" shape that is raised more in the centre than the sides.

Now the problem I have :

What do I call a distribution like this?
What is the general formula for this type of distribution? It seems like a normal distribution with a twist.

Comment: Have a look at this list of distributions, http://geocities.com/~mikemclaughlin/math_stat/Dists/Compendium.html Folded Normal looks to work, have never heard of it!

Comment: Thank you man.  This is exactly what I needed.  It does seem to be a Folded ND.  Now I just have to rotate it out the y-axis. haha